# OpenCPU Server (public) installed package

Tags: r, package, opencpu

**BACKGROUND**

I am using the opencpu server (public) to perform some calculations.

```
ocpu.seturl("https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/base/R")
```

Until recently, everything was running perfectly.

**ISSUE**

But I noticed a few weeks ago that I got an error from the server as a package **deSolve** was not installed. I am sure it was installed previously as everything was running (and I was using some functions from this package).

Is there a way to see installed packages ?

**SOLUTION ?**

And should I then run my own openCPU server to solve this issue ?

Best,

W

Answer (score 1):

You can use the webhook to install an app on the server. An app is simply an R package. If your R package imports deSolve, it will automatically be installed as well.